Basement bulkhead, heavy objects?
Reviewer say too much word, need picture. Here picture. Measured picture later.
Word still need: Steps wood, lift out, heavy. Want help lift stairs, other heavy things, out and in, no hurt. Think block tackle or crane but may be very wrong.






I think you know that this is all entirely subjective.

There are small cranes that fit on truck beds.  Maybe one or something similar mounted on a concrete pad.

@isherwood: not looking for best, which is indeed subjective. Looking for approaches to consider, preferably ones that have worked.

I am thinking this will be more of side/angle pulling than straight up and down.  If so the pull device will need good anchor point so it does not move/is pulled towards the weight lifting.  A crane/winch that can fit into thick wall steel pipe.

The only questions you actually post are about "fantasy" (subjective) and cost. Both are off topic. If you're asking how it might be done, it seems like you'd want to post a photo. Any answers will be very general, otherwise.

Hmm. Ok, if that's your perception, I won't argue it. If you want full photos and dimensions I can do that, but it will take a few days extra... and I think many, perhaps most, Americans know exactly the arrangement I'm describing, so I didn't feel a need for that level of detail. The big thing I left out was that a porch encroaches in one side, but I don't think that affects the answer a great deal. So: Photos to follow; if you want to vote to close for now  and then vote whether to reopen when the pix are added  I'm not going to try to stop you.

Note that I didn't ask cost. Note too that the point of my question is whether this "can" reasonably/easily be done or if I'm deluding myself. And I think you're confusing me with someone else; I don't ask many questions, and I don't think those I do skew toward unreasonable. I don't know if our histories are visible in our public profiles, nut you might want to check mine. Meanwhile I'm just assuming you're having a bad day; you're better than this.

Edit. Snarky, but edit. Still want full dimensioned diagrams, or is there another way I can clarify? This is external home improvement, but certainly home improvement.

Hopefully to get this back on track: Keshlam: I've seen you enough around here to know that YOU KNOW you can build a ramp to get up the step from outside and use a stair dolly to handle up to a few hundred pounds.  So, constructively I hope, the question would be better if you explained how that is not good enough.  A crane? Are you lifting something that's much much more than 300 pounds?  If so, maybe make the question specific to your requirement.

I have tried using a stair dolly on those steps.  Control was bad, even with people  on guy ropes stabilizing. So, no, I don't "know," that is the best answer, though I'm willing to accept that it may be.  If that's your answer, great, answer (preferably with advice on how to do it right) and I'll certainly up-vote and consider accepting.  You've also been here long enough to know how SE works; this is a legitimate question that anyone with this construction (not uncommon in the Eastern US) might run into. Frame challenge is appropriate, and welcome. I still don't see cause for closing.

Should we take this to Meta?

(I'm also not going to fight over it. If people don't feel it's worth reopening, that's fine too.)

Another thing that might work would be a safe-mover's dolly, which has a powered assist built into it for moving from step to step. Fine device, expensive, a bit bulky to store, not ideally suited for stairs with no risers but I could add risers, doesn't help if the object is bulky enough that first step has to be to move the stairs out of the way. Any yes, this should be in Answers but with the question locked ..

I'm on the fence keshlam.  I didn't VtC but  I think the question needs more detail to produce an answer that has any hope of being useful to someone like you, IE, someone with reasonable DIY experience already.   And I don't think "use a stair dolly" is worthy of an answer, for the same reason.   If you said "I just bought my first house and I don't know what these weird stairs are for" etc etc, I might write an answer like "Behold!  A stair dolly!"  Anyway,  I can't now.

If I could answer, I might also suggest a couple of 2x6s laid flat on the stairs, an old piece of carpet for a sled, and a hand winch tied to a stake in the lawn.  This is after all "DIY" ... Behold! A funicular railway.

@jay613: tried essentially that approach when moving the table saw in. Did not feel safe/reliable, hence my wanting a better answer. But I grant that this may be too much of a brainstorming question, and for that reason i'm becoming convinced that I should withdraw it. Was just hoping that there actually was a canonical solution..

Reopen request retracted.

The easiest solution is one of:
Either an A-frame hoist with a crossbeam that extends over the bulkhead opening, so the A-frame feet are outside it, or an engine hoist with wide enough legs that you can straddle a corner of the opening and get the hook in. Both of those don't depend on the house for support at all. They disassemble into more-easily carried and stored parts. You might want to do some concrete work to give them a hard surface to roll on near the bulkhead.
Next up would be (assuming typical concrete bulkhead) a "back of pickup truck" (or for larger aspirations back of a bigger truck) hoist/crane that would slot into a hole provided for it in the concrete wall of the bulkhead (or a steel sleeve for it bolted to the wall of the bulkhead.) The pickup truck sized version can certainly be pulled out of the sleeve or hole and stored elsewhere between uses. Again, no load on the house.

A-frame was my first thought as well. The 10,000 pound winch on my truck was another option (with nobody underneath the load).

Good thoughts. I was too focused on "from above".

A-frames and engine hoists are for up/down.  They should not be used for angle pulls like up/down stairs.  Have an A-frame for a cow lift.  Much more than 10 or 20 degree angle and the legs will start to lift.

@crip659 So, you make the stairs easily removable, and it's a dead lift to/from a flat surface with them out.

@crip659: The current  stairs are removable, though heavy enough that the crane/lift/whatever would help with that too.
